# Access Apache NiFi running on remote VM via browser and PuTTY

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, putty

I'm trying to access a Virtual Machine running in Google Cloud which has a Apache NiFi service running on port 8080 on the VM. I have managed to create an ssh key and upload the public SSH key to the cloud to access the machine.

I've tested connecting to the VM via the command line, from my Windows machine, and everything is working. I've read that in order to access the remote 8080 port on the VM I need to tunnel.

I installed Putty and configured it so that I have access to the same command line terminal as I have from the regular Windows command line. I've set up the tunneling configuration on Putty and I would expect that when I access localhost:8383 on my machine, to have my connection tunneled to the remote vm's 8080 port.

[image]

However, when I try to access localhost:8383 in my Firefox browser on my Windows computer, nothing happens. When trying to access this url in my browser I still have Putty's command line connection to the VM OPEN.

I'm not sure what to do next. Any ideas are appreciated!